# Storing large CSV file with version control

Tags: git, controls, version, perforce

We have an use-case where we need to store large csv (each file can be of 1-5 GB and there can be total around 50-100 files) files and manage version control for them.
Also we need to support operations like

1. Exporting the files
2. Update, Add , Delete rows from the file and storing them as new version. The edit/add/delete operations is likely to e smaller (like say 1000lines max)
3. Finding the difference between two version of the file.
4. Load the file into database.
5. Export file from database into version control system
6. Get file for certain version number.

With the file size and the operations which would be a better option like Perforce Vs Git Vs SVN.

Comment: Those are all pretty basic operations, and are supported by a wide range of version control systems. What's your specific question?

Answer (score -1):

Best choice for versioning big files is Mercurial with LargeFiles extension enabled